# What is a quasi-isomorphism of complexes of vector bundles?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, homological-algebra, differential-topology

Consider a homomorphism $f$ between two complexes of vector bundles over a fixed smooth manifold $M$.
$$
\cdots \to V_{i - 1} \xrightarrow{\delta_{i-1}} V_i \xrightarrow{\delta_i} V_{i + 1} \to \cdots
$$
$$
\cdots \to W_{i - 1} \xrightarrow{\Delta_{i-1}} W_i \xrightarrow{\Delta_i} W_{i + 1} \to \cdots
$$
When people (e.g. those working in derived algebraic geometry) say that $f$ is a quasi-isomorphism, does that simply mean that we have isomorphisms $\frac{\ker \delta_i}{\operatorname{im} \delta_{i-1}}|_x \to \frac{\ker \Delta_i}{\operatorname{im} \Delta_{i-1}}|_x$ for all $x \in M$?

I'm worried since $\frac{\ker \delta_i}{\operatorname{im} \delta_{i-1}}$ may not form a smooth vector bundle.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isomorphism

Comment: Dear @Sasha, his question seems reasonable to me. The category of vector bundles is not abelian, so I would imagine that some care must be taken to make sense of quasi-isomorphisms.

Comment: @Gabriel: But the category of coherent sheaves is, and a morphism of complexes of vector bundles is a quasiisomorphis if and only if it is a quasiisomorphism when considered as a morphism of complexes of coherent sheaves.

Comment: Perfect, so this seems to answer his question.

Comment: Is being a quasi-isomorphism of complexes of coherent sheaves equivalent to the pointwise condition in the question?

Comment: No, it is not. For instance take $M = \mathbb{A}^1$, the first complex $$\mathcal{O} \stackrel{t^2}\to \mathcal{O},$$ the second complex $$\mathcal{O} \stackrel{t}\to \mathcal{O},$$ and the morphism $(t,1)$. Then the pointwise condition is satisfied, but the morphism is not a quasiisomorphism.

Comment: I think it would help to clarify the precise context and the meaning of the notation. Generally speaking, in either differential or algebraic geometry, I would say that a quasi-isomorphism of vector bundles means a quasi-isomorphism of the corresponding sheaves of sections. This means that $f$ induces isomorphisms on homology sheaves. This latter condition can be checked pointwise on *stalks* of the homology sheaves, but I guess the pointwise condition in mentioned in the question is supposed to refer to the *fibers* at $x$ rather than stalks (which is not sufficient to check isomorphisms.)